# What is a good Rails logging solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to do advanced logging:

1. Unlimited log size
2. Ability to filter by priorities (debug/info/error)
3. Ability to filter by models/custom- tag
4. Ability to filter by user-sessions (see only errors for a specific session)
5. Should be able to work on Heroku
6. *Optional: Set rules to email/sms on certain high-priority errors

Either a tool that works with files and can easily diesct them, or a DB backed log storage.

Any suggestions are most welcome

Comment: This sounds like a lot of requests from a logger. I would consider the 'do-it-yourself' method to be the greatest in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Log4r](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/) first; if it doesn't do *exactly* what you need, it's pretty tweakable.